# Why memcache Yii2 not set value with duration parameter

Tags: yii2, memcached

I using Memcache to cache data in project yii2.
with config:

```
'cache' => [
        'class' => 'yii\caching\MemCache',
        'servers' => [
            [
                'host' => 'localhost',
                'port' => 11211,
            ],
        ],
    ],
```

With code: return false

```
\Yii::$app->cache->set('abc', 'value of abc', 20); // 20 seconds
$data = \Yii::$app->cache->get('abc'); var_dump($data); // return false
```

But if i set:

    `\Yii::$app->cache->set('abc', 'value of abc', -20); // -20 seconds $data = \Yii::$app->cache->get('abc'); var_dump($data); // return "value of abc"`

So why this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Can you increment the seconds?

Pls try this and let me know the results:

```
\Yii::$app->cache->set('abc', 'value of abc', 10000); 
$data = \Yii::$app->cache->get('abc'); var_dump($data);
```

Comment: it still return false.

Comment: Can you predict reason?

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but in case someone else have same problem, here are my thoughts...

It might depend on whether MemCached or MemCache is installed. If config uses MemCache (like in the question) but MemCached is installed, it will work using get() but set() is different after the two first parameters, ie duration.